# Swift - how can I ensure a class gets compiled even if it appears unused?

Tags: swift, xcode, loading, compiler-optimization, xpc

My setup is the following: I have an app target `App` with custom class `Foo` that is used in a parameter to a protocol that is being used to communicate over XPC. The AppDelegate for `App` implements this protocol, e.g.:

```
@objc(Foo) class Foo { ... }

protocol XPCProtocol {
   func myFunc(foo: Foo)
}

class AppDelegate: NSApplicationDelegate, XPCProtocol {
   ...
   func myFunc(foo: Foo) { ... }
}
```

In my use case, `myFunc` is never invoked from my app target `App`, but by another process via XPC. However, it seems that because `App` never invokes it, and that is the only usage of `Foo`, the `Foo` class seems to not get compiled (whenever I invoke `myFunc` from the other process, it says that `Foo` is not loaded or does not exist).

Further indication that this is a compilation issue is the fact that if I simply instantiate `Foo` anywhere in `App`, via `let _ = Foo()`, the problem goes away. However, I would really prefer to avoid solving a compiler issue this way.

So, is there any way I can mark my `Foo` class so that the compiler always includes it? I already have Swift Compiler optimization turned off in my Xcode build settings, so I'm not sure what else I can do.